# Can't Open from Source Control in TFS

Tags: tfs

I don't know what happened here, but I wanted to open a project from a different Source Control or a different TFS server using VS 2010.  From File->Source Control->Open From Source Control, I could find the PC where the TFS server is running, however, the OK button is disabled or can't be clicked, even if the WorkSpace and Local Path entries are filled.  I've tried removing the entire VS 2010 and re-installed again, but still this problem exists, what could be the cause here?  What's the only premise that the OK button could be clickable?  Thanks.

Frederick

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to change the TFS server you are connected to. Select "Team | Connect to Team Foundation Server" and select or add the new TFS server.

If you get a blank source control window with the Workspaces grayed out / dissabled and no Source Control option when you right click on a project then you probably need to change the provider.

Go to "Tools | Options | Source Control" and make sure that the provider is set to "Team Foundation Server".

Comment: I did Connect to a different Foundation Server, but in my Team Explorer pane, it only shows my Work Items, Builds, etc.  Can't see any Model, Views or Controllers folders and the rest of my work... :(

Answer (score 3):

Got the cause of the error... The primary cause was the solution file was not there in the first place, thus making the OK button unclickable... Our admin thought he had everything up already... thanks for your time :D